# Intellij can't find commons.dbcp2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, apache-commons

I have a problem which drives me insane, since it should work.

I have compiled dbcp dependency in my gradle file

```
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
```

still, it can't resolve if i refer to it like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
```

[image]

Any idea? (using intellij)

Comment: Can you check if the dependency was added to your project's classpath? If it's not, try clicking the little [refresh button](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html) from the gradle tool window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the gradle project was unlinked, so the dependencies - even thought the dependencies was there in the external libraries, i had to re-link the gradle.